# How Do I Use Restfull Webservices with Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

How do I use RESTfull Web services with Cakephp? I have already done 2 projects in cakephp, have a basic idea about the cakephp and its structure
Please advise me

Comment: "Use" as in "consume" or as in "provide"? Also, what have you tried, where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Yup..I am serving a web service to iPhone app ,really iPhone is consuming the web service ,so I want to write in inside the cakephp

Answer (score 0):

To provide RESTful services, check out the RequestHandler component for your controllers and and parseExtensions in the router. There's a really good video on the CakePHP website that should get you started: http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2010/12/24/andrew_curioso_-_developing_an_api

Comment: Thank you ..let me check videos

Comment: How do I use a url ,like structure of url I am not able to get the xml page as per the video.Always it is not catching the view file.Any working example or link there?